# Where should persistence logic be put in Doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

Doctrine repositories are the place where queries are put if you want to share them across your application.

Is it a good idea to put persistence logic in the repository, so that repositories would be useful for not just querying, but also creating and updating objects?

Is there any other place for persistence logic that is not in the controller itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put it into the [service layer](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html). In this case, your controllers know only the service layer, but no repository layer. The service layer can delegate queries to the repository layer or do them by itself — I prefer the latter.

Just a basic example:

```
class CommentService
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function find($id) 
    {
        // do a query here or delegate to a repository
    }

    public function findByPost(Post $post)
    {
        // do a query here or delegate to a repository
    }

    public function save(Comment $comment)
    {
        // exec an operation here
    }

    public function delete(Comment $comment)
    {
        // exec an operation here
    }
}
```

Comment: what about folder-wise?? i have my entities in a the lib folder of my Zend project, as specified by documentation, should i put my repositories alongside them?